# Python: Passing parameters by name

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

Hi I was wondering how to implement this in python. Lets say for example you have a function with two parameters and both print out to console

```
def myFunc(varA, varB):
    print 'varA=', varA
    print 'varB=', varB
```

I have seen libraries (pymel being the one that comes to mind) where it allows you to specify the parameter you are parsing data too by name in no specific order. for example

```
myFunc(varB=12, varA = 'Tom')
```

I am not sure what I am missing as this doesn't seem to work when I try to declare my own functions inside or outside the maya environment.

Any clues would be wonderful, thank you in advanced.

Comment: post your code with error being reported

Comment: You can do that with any existing python function... what's wrong with that?

Comment: Most common error is using a keyword argument before a non keyword but, yeah post your code

Comment: Argh I am so sorry I was accidentally using the wrong textMate language settings

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's normal Python behavior. If you're seeing errors then you're goofing up something else (e.g. missing a required parameter, trying to pass positional arguments by name, etc.).

```
>>> def func(foo, bar):
...   print foo, bar
... 
>>> func(bar='quux', foo=42)
42 quux
```

Comment: yeah it was a goof, I will give you this answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for a way to implement named parameters in Python functions, which allows you to pass arguments to a function by specifying the parameter names, regardless of their order. This is a common feature in many Python libraries.

In your example, you want to be able to call myFunc with named parameters like this:

```
myFunc(varB=12, varA='Tom')
```

This is actually a standard feature in Python. Your function definition is correct, but you might be using an older version of Python (before Python 3) where the syntax is slightly different. In Python 2, you would use print as a statement, but in Python 3, it is a function.

Here's an updated version of your code that works in both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
def myFunc(varA, varB):
    print('varA=', varA)
    print('varB=', varB)

# Call the function with named parameters
myFunc(varB=12, varA='Tom')
```

Make sure you are using a version of Python that supports this syntax. If you are using Python 2, consider upgrading to Python 3, as Python 2 has reached the end of its life and is no longer supported.